# Is it possible to write in an existing spreadSheet with PhpSpreadSheet?

Tags: php, spreadsheet, phpspreadsheet

I'm currently using PhpSpreadSheet Library and I wanna write into an existing spreadSheet. Is that possible?

If yes, how? I didn't see any possibility in the [documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/#writing-a-spreadsheet).

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

- Load the existing Spreadsheet-File
- Change something
- Write it again to Filesystem

Code:

```
<?php

//load spreadsheet
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load("yourspreadsheet.xlsx");

//change it
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'New Value');

//write it again to Filesystem with the same name (=replace)
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('yourspreadsheet.xlsx');
```

Comment: the documentation Vs @Evil_skunk ... man thank you very much... wtf doc phpspreadsheet is this ??????????? I was looking for this answer like 20 min