# How to write on an exiting spreadsheet with PHPSpreadsheet?

Tags: php, xlsx, phpspreadsheet

I want to modify an existing spreadsheet with PHPspreadsheet and then save it.

I tried this code:

```
<?php

//load spreadsheet
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load("yourspreadsheet.xlsx");

//change it
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'New Value');

//write it again to Filesystem with the same name (=replace)
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('yourspreadsheet.xlsx');
```

I've found it on this question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609059/is-it-possible-to-write-in-an-existing-spreadsheet-with-phpspreadsheet)

but unfortunately it return this error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx::__construct() must be an instance of PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet, null given
```

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: have you tried reading the documentation?
https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/#reading-and-writing-to-file

Comment: Yes, it didn't give much info about this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example code for spreadsheet:

```
    $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader("Xlsx");
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load('yourspreadsheet.xlsx');
 
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $last_row = (int) $sheet->getHighestRow();
    $new_row = $last_row+1;
 
    $sheet->setCellValue('A'.$new_row, "14");
    $sheet->setCellValue('B'.$new_row, "Alina");
    $sheet->setCellValue('C'.$new_row, "PG");
    $sheet->setCellValue('D'.$new_row, "$32");
    $sheet->setCellValue('E'.$new_row, "Pending");
 
    $writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, "Xlsx");
    $writer->save('yourspreadsheet.xlsx');
```

Comment: @LOUIZYSALAH - I tried your approach and then tried PHPHupTechnologies method and I am still have the same issue